# MYSQL Query - Find the customers who ordered a specific product HELP

Tags: mysql, query

[image: ERD]Samsung had a defect in their Samsung Galaxy(ProductName) product. Customers who bought this product are being refunded. Which customers should be contacted(First Name and Last Name)?

Comment: Eh?  One "Payment" can be associated with many "Customers"?  Focus on "1-to-many" vs "many-to-many".  They are implemented differently.

Answer (score 0):

ER diagram is the map of data, which helps us to discover the route and to navigate through the data world.

1. You have the product name, which is in the product table and it’s identified by product_id.
2. Follow the line from product_id to another product_id in order detail table and you get order_id.
3. Follow the line to order table and you get customer_id.
4. Again, follow the line to customer table (you can skip customer_address because customer_id is the primary key of customer table).
5. Now join all the line you just discovered and that is how you join tables together: from product_name to customer name.
6. The rest is translating the route into SQL select with inner joins and where clause. That’s it. Have fun in the adventure of data world.

[image]